# Change SELECT-OPTIONS text programmatically

Tags: selection, abap, dynpro

I'm trying to replace the **selection-option** name when it's showed in the screen by **using abap code**. not the "*Goto->Text Elements->Selection Text*".

If there is any kind of solution with you please share with me.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.. :) :) :)

---

```
 INITIALIZATION.
 %_name_%_app_%-text = 'Carrier ID'.
```

---